# tag not receiving the model bean (it's null) but containing page does?

Tags: playframework

We are testing out playframework from a port of a few pages of our seam application.  We have one page where alot of the html is reused between two forms where one form adds 3 more fields.  After porting this, we discovered that

The email is ${user.email}

works in the containing page but in the tag page, playframework says user is null????  What is going on?  Is this a bug or is this intended?  Aren't tag files useless if I can't access dynamic data? so I believe it has to be me, but I cut and paste the same line.  Any ideas?  Anyone have a simple case like this that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are self contained, and do not assume that data or items exist. This is because a tag can be re-used between many pages. Therefore, you have to pass any data items into the tags as parameters.

Comment: duh, I should have realized that(only my second day on play but I have been passing other things to tags)...thanks!!!